# How do I make a good JSON output from existing arrays?

Tags: php, json

An app developer would like to receive data from my API in the following JSON format:

```
{"response":1,"values":[{"brid": 31,"description": "Painter"},{"brid":33,"description":"Plumber"}]}
```

I managed to produce this:

```
{"result":[{"response":1},{"brids":["1","2","3","4","5"]},{"descriptions":["Plumber","Carpenter","Electrician","Mason","Painter"]}]}
```

By using this code:

```
$result=array();
$result[]['response']=intval(1); 
$result[]['brids']=$brids;
$result[]['descriptions']=$descriptions;
$response["result"]=$result;
echo json_encode($response);
```

And I managed to produce this:

```
{"response":1,"0":{"brid":1,"description":"Plumber"},"1":{"brid":2,"description":"Carpenter"},"2":{"brid":3,"description":"Electrician"},"3":{"brid":4,"description":"Mason"},"4":{"brid":5,"description":"Painter"}}
```

by using this code:

```
$test=array();
$test['response']=intval(1);
for ($i=0;$i<count($brids);$i++)
{
    $value=array();
    $value['brid']=intval($brids[$i]);
    $value['description']=$descriptions[$i];
    $test[]=$value;
}
echo json_encode($test);
```

How do I satisfy the developer?

Albert

Answer (score 2):

Loop over one of the arrays (both have to be of the same size) a foreach is simplest using the form that captures the key `$i` in your code.

Build a temp array containing the inner objects

Then simpy add them to the outer array

```
$descriptions = ["Plumber","Carpenter","Electrician","Mason","Painter"];
$brids = [31,32,33,34,35];

$out['response'] = 1;
foreach ( $brids as $i => $brid ){
    $t = ['brid' => $brid, 'description' => $descriptions[$i]];
    $out['values'][] = $t;
}
echo json_encode($out);
```

RESULT

```
{
    "response":1,
    "values":[
                {"brid":31,"description":"Plumber"},
                {"brid":32,"description":"Carpenter"},
                {"brid":33,"description":"Electrician"},
                {"brid":34,"description":"Mason"},
                {"brid":35,"description":"Painter"}
            ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

you're pretty close, this should work:

```
$test = [
   'response' => 1,
   'values'   => []
];
for ($i=0;$i<count($brids);$i++){
    $test['values'][] = (object) [
        'brid'        => intval($brids[$i]),
        'description' => $descriptions[$i]
    ];
}
echo json_encode($test);
```

so instead of pushing directly to `$test` with `$test[]`, you push to its `value` attribute

Be aware that `$descriptions[$i]` inside the `for` it's a bit risky, there might be few elements in `$descriptions` than in `$birds` (at least for the code you have provided)

Comment: Cool. If the first suggestion didn't work, I will try this one, tomorrow :) I will let everyone know which one I chose

Comment: Well, I'd like to thank all participants in this thread. All three suggestions worked. I had to chose one (three wouldn't be appreciated by my app developer), so I chose Alberto Sinigaglias suggestion.

Comment: @Kairos well thank you, glad to see it helped

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. You just need to wrap your values array into a key in existing response.

```
$test=array();
$test['response']=intval(1);
$testValues=array()
for ($i=0;$i<count($brids);$i++)
{
    $value=array();
    $value['brid']=intval($brids[$i]);
    $value['description']=$descriptions[$i];
    $testValues[]=$value;
}
$test['values']=$testValues;
echo json_encode($test);
```

Comment: That looks very logical. Thank you. I got two other suggestions, if they don't work (I doubt it, but you never know before you've tried), I will try this one!

Comment: @Kairos Sure 